# Sharing field constraints between server and client side

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot, jpa

I am working on a project, where server side is based on Spring Boot 2, and front-end is based on Angular.

On the server side, in the data model classes I have declarations like that:

```
@Column(length = 256, nullable = false)
@Size(max = 256)
private String subject;
```

I would like to implement field length validation also on the front-end (angular side).

What is the best approach to share field length constraints between server and client side?

I do not like the idea that I need to repeat myself and hard-code field length on the both sides (server and client side).

Is it the best approach in my case if I declare set of constants like this:

```
private static final int maxSubjectLength = 256;
```

And use them as follows:

```
@Column(length = maxSubjectLength, nullable = false)
@Size(max = maxSubjectLength)
private String subject;
```

Then make a configuration class with these constants, which instance is accessible via `GET` http-request?

Or there is a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use the following approach. Assume we have a model class `Question`, that has a property `body`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Questions")
public final class Question {

    // other properties & code

    private String body;

    // other properties & code
}
```

And we want to limit the body length to `1024` symbols and define this limit only once, on the server and use this limit on the back-end and on the front-end of the application.

On the server side, in our model class `Question` we define static map, that contains size limits for all class properties.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Questions")
public final class Question {

    private static class ModelConstraints {
        static final int MAX_BODY_LENGTH = 1024;
        // limits for other fields are going here
    }

    private static final Map<String, Integer> modelConstraintsMap;

    static
    {
        final Map<String, Integer> localConstraintsMap = new HashMap<>();
        localConstraintsMap.put("MAX_BODY_LENGTH", ModelConstraints.MAX_BODY_LENGTH);
        // .... putting all constants from ModelConstraints to the map here

        // composing unmodifable map    
        modelConstraintsMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(localConstraintsMap);
    }

    @Column(length = ModelConstraints.MAX_BODY_LENGTH, nullable = false)
    @Size(max = ModelConstraints.MAX_BODY_LENGTH)
    private String body;

    // other properties and code

    public static Map<String, Integer> getModelConstraintsMap() {
        return modelConstraintsMap;
    }   

    // other properties and code
}
```

Internal class `ModelConstraints` contains definitions of max length values for all relevant model properties.

In the static block, I create an unmodifiable map, that contains these constraints and I return this map via public method.

In the controller, related to the model class I add a rest-endpoint that returns property length constraints.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/questions/model-constraints", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Integer>> getModelConstraints() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(Question.getModelConstraintsMap(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This method returns json-representation of the map with the property length constraints.

On the (angular) fron-tend I call this end-point and set `maxlength` property of form fields, related to the model class properties.

In the component typescript file I add and call this method:

```
  loadConstraints() {
    var url: string = "/questions/model-constraints";
    this.http
      .get(url)
      .subscribe((data: Map<string, number>) => (this.modelConstraints = data));
  }
```

And after call of this method the component property `modelConstraints` will contain map with field length constraints.

I set these constraints in the component template (html) file.

```
  <textarea
    matInput
    rows="7"
    placeholder="Question body"
    maxlength="{{ modelConstraints['MAX_BODY_LENGTH'] }}"
    [(ngModel)]="questionBody"
  ></textarea>
```

That's it. Using this approach you can define field length only once, on the server and use this definition on the server and on the client.